# Rails route error with mozilla

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have added links to pages in rails application, its working fine in google chrome but in mozilla firefox its showing error

```
No route matches [GET] "/home"
Rails.root: C:/Users/walnut/Desktop/projects/garden
```

Here i am trying to add anchor link to pages.

here is how i have added link

file: navbar.html.erb

```
 <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
```

its working quite fine in chrome but mozilla firefox is showing error.

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add / before home:

```
 <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
```

But should be better if you use the rails link_to method.